# How to locate elements in protractor using custom html tags?

Tags: html, jquery, automated-tests, protractor, ui-automation

I have the following HTML  for the rows in the table.

```
<tr [attr.row-index]="i" data-test="value-row" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: objectKeys(displayedColumns); index as i"></tr>
```

To get the row in protractor testing, I am using the following xpath.

```
const rowElem = element(by.xpath('//table//tbody//tr[@row-index="0"]'));
```

This is working as jQuery in the web tools console for Chrome, however, in the test, I am getting the following error.

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //vv-data-table//tbody//tr[@row-index="0"])
```

I am doubtful that the row-index is causing the issue, because if I use an xpath without the `row-index` tag, as given below, then it works fine.

```
const rowElem = element(by.xpath('//table//tbody//tr[1]'));
```

I am really not able to understand why this is happening and I am new to protractor testing. Any clue or idea would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `browser.$(...)` (equivalent to `browser.element(by.css(...))`) which allows to find an element by selector (same as you do with `jQuery`, and same as `document.querySelector(selector)` in browser console):

```js
const rowElem = browser.$('table tbody tr[row-index=0]');
```

or in your case:

```js
const rowElem = browser.$('vv-data-table tbody tr[row-index=0]');
```